# FragmentTabHost in VS2013 - xamarin C#

Tags: c#, android, mono

the code i used to create FragmentTabHost :( i am designing for android 2.2 to upper)
i have googled a lot but no use so
i have placed all of my code here.
I get error in :

```
   mTabHost.AddTab(spec);
```

please help how to solve ??

Activity 2.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Support.V4.App;


namespace ANRestaurant.Forms
{
[Activity(Label = "ANRestaurant", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]


public class Activity2 : FragmentActivity
{
    FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);


        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        try
        {
            mTabHost = FindViewById<FragmentTabHost>(Resource.Id.tabhostN  );
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Fragment1));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            //mTabHost.Setup(this, SupportFragmentManager, Resource.Id.tabFrameLayout);


            TabHost.TabSpec spec;
            spec = mTabHost.NewTabSpec("artists");
            spec.SetIndicator("Artists", Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.tab_icon1)  );
            spec.SetContent(intent);
            mTabHost.AddTab(spec);   ======>Here is the error
            //mTabHost.AddTab(
            //        mTabHost.NewTabSpec("tab2").SetIndicator("Tab 2", null),
            //       intent, null);
            //mTabHost.addTab(
            //        mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2", null),
            //        FragmentTab.class, null);
            //mTabHost.addTab(
            //        mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3", null),
            //        FragmentTab.class, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.axml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhostN"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>`

Fragment1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;


namespace ANRestaurant.Forms
{
public class Fragment1 : Fragment
{



    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // Create your fragment here
    }
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, container, false);
       return view;
         //return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
}
```

ٍError Is :
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type  Java.Lang.NullPointerException  was thrown.
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms)

Comment: "I get error" doesn't tell us what the error *is*. Please give the full details.

Comment: Could you please post the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

I have done that by :
changing :

`mTabHost.AddTab(spec);`

To :

`mTabHost.Setup(this, SupportFragmentManager, Resource.Id.tabFrameLayout);
mTabHost.AddTab(spec, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Fragment1)), null);`

End!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and found here.
The problem is here in your fragment:

```
using Android.App;
```

Change it to:

```
using Android.Support.V4.App;
```

It's ok now...

It waste me the whole day.

OK, in output window it shows cast type error. like this：

```
Android.App.Fragment can't cast to Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.
```